# C# - SMTP - GoDaddy - Send Email not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SendAlertEmail(string EMAIL, string UNIQUE_CODE)
        {
            var smtpHost = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
            var smtpPort = 25;
            var smtpUsername = "helpdesk@manappuramfoundation.com";
            var smtpPassword = "*********";
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("helpdesk@manappuramfoundation.com", "ALERT");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress(EMAIL);
            var subject = "Reset Password - Unique Code";
            var body = "Dear User,\n\nYou have requested to reset your password for the HELPDESK MODULE. " +
                       "Please use the following unique code for login:\n\n" + UNIQUE_CODE + "\n\n" +
                       "Thank you for using our service.\n\nBest regards,\nThe HELPDESK Team";

            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress))
            {
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.Body = body;

                using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, smtpPort))
                {
                    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

                    try
                    {
                        // Asynchronously send the email
                        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
                    }
                    catch (SmtpException ex)
                    {
                        // An error occurred while sending the email, handle or log the exception.
                        TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Failed to send alert email: " + ex.Message;
                    }
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

code not working.need to find solution.how to setup smtp mail service in GoDaddy.need to send smtp mail though godaddy.i have tyied though local with below code its working fine.
 `var smtpHost = "smtp.office365.com"; var smtpPort = 587; var smtpUsername = "helpdesk@manappuramfoundation.com"; var smtpPassword = "******";`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Port 25 is unsecure email while Port 587 is secure.  You must read the GoDaddy SMTP webpage to determine how to configure you SMTP.  Most email servers require port 587 and require Credentials and not a username and password.  Credentials use an encrypted password with username/password the password is not encrypted.